# I can be good in a fight

Tags: riddle, word

> If you are in me
>
> My name on your breath
>
> Will surely begin me
>
> Yet end soon in death
>
> I'll shock you when high
>
> I'll please you when low
>
> But fail to defend me
>
> To jail you may go

What am I?

The answer is a single word. Please explain how it relates to each line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is:

> Charge

If you are in me

> If you are in charge...

My name on your breath

> Shouting “Charge”...

Will surely begin me

> Will start a charge...

Yet end soon in death

> Which will not last long but will lead to deaths on one side or another.

I'll shock you when high

> If the charge for something is too high, you’ll be unhappy. Alternatively a high electrical charge will provide a shock.

I'll please you when low

> But if it’s lower than expected you’ll be pleased

But fail to defend me

To jail you may go

> If you are in a criminal court on charges and fail to defend them, you may end up in jail.
> An explosive charge can be good in a fight.

Comment: Correct in every detail!