# Many forms I take

Tags: riddle, english

> Many forms I take
>   Unification I aim to make
>   I can make you act quite dumb
>   Cause your tongue to go numb
>
> Appearing in every nation
>   I am the cause of relation
>   I can control
>   Even animals
>
> Father and son
>   I think I've won
>   Mother and child
>   Even in the wild
>
> You'll never be alone
>   I'm accessible over phone
>   I am quite widespread and powerful
>   But if you're not careful
>
> I can ruin your life.

*Who or what is this?!?*

Comment: I don't quite get the downvote. Someone wish to explain?

Comment: To be honest, it's just kinda boring. There have been a large influx of riddles recently, most of them mediocre - there's nothing clever about this, it's just a standard riddle subject with standard rhyme scheme, a couple oddly worded clues ("accessible over phone"?), and no wordplay or other interesting elements whatsoever - it's not even redeemed by the meter, because that's inconsistent. I don't mean to be harsh, but it's just... boring.

Comment: Love? Ain't nobody got time fo dat

Comment: @warspyking To some degree, this riddle is a victim of circumstance. Two weeks ago, this would have had 5 up-votes, but just in the last week the number of unsolved riddles on Puzzling has more than tripled, and the community is getting picky. For the record, I didn't think this deserved down-votes, just sharing my theory.

Comment: I didn't _quite_ think this was good enough to upvote, but it definitely doesn't deserve a score of -7! I might upvote anyway just to compensate :-) Could it be an ad-hominem effect? "Oh, it's the guy with loads of negative-scored questions; this one's probably crappy too." (I know you have lots of good ones as well, but people mainly remember you for the bad ones!)

Comment: @rand al'thor Let's keep in mind I have more 0+ questions than negatively scored questions (excluding deleted because I can't find them!) as I continue to say!

Comment: That's why I put the sentence in brackets at the end! :-)

Comment: @rand al'thor :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is -

> Love?

Because-

> Love can be in many forms.
>   Love can definitely make people act quite dumb.
>   Love is in every nation and drives animals to reproduce.
>   Love is between father and son and mother and child.
>   Love is widespread and can be powerful and can also ruin your life ex: loving the wrong people. 
>   However I don't know how accessible over the phone it is :/

Comment: You're correct. Very poor formatting though. (You can talk in long distance relationships over the phone)

Comment: May I recommend formatting it like here: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/20439/2383

Comment: Oops sorry :/ I'm quite new to this. Thank you for the referral.

Comment: It's quite fine. Would it be too much for you to explain each line though? It's kind of standard.